# Проблема с z-index

Tags: html, css

Есть проблема с наложением элемента с абсолютным позиционированием.

Вот пример.

```css
.d1,.d2{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  position:relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: green;
}
.subdiv{
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 50px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
    <div class="subdiv"></div>
</div>
<div class="d2"></div>
```

Проблема в том что `div` с `class="subdiv"` не видно из за второго элемента с ՝class="d2"՝.

Как можно решить эту проблему.

Примечание:

> `z-index: 1;` обязателен у меня для блоков `class="d1"` и `class="d2"`.

Comment: Сделайте `d1` `z-index: 2`, в чём проблема?)

Comment: @meine У меня там блоки идентичны, в цикле, и нельзя угадать у кого будет `subdiv`.

Comment: Добавить проверку в какой блок попал subdiv на js и ему увеличивать z-index

Comment: @РашенБеар ну а только с помощью `css` никак да ?

Comment: @ RazGalstyan Думаю, что нет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.d1,.d2{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  position:relative;
  z-index: auto;
  background: green;
}
.subdiv{
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 50px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
    <div class="subdiv"></div>
</div>
<div class="d2"></div>
```